Why is my histogram plotting differently than my datatable?
I am plotting my dataset to a DataTable and a Histogram using Plotly Dash. The DataTable plots the data accurately, but the Histogram combines data across dates in my dataset and I can't figure out why.
The DataTable displays 7 days of data, which is correct. The histogram only displays 4 days, adding together August 15 & 16, 17 & 18, 19 & 20 instead of displaying them as individual bars.
Screenshot
Here is my code:
# Incorporate data
df = pd.json_normalize(sales.json()['payload'], 
                     meta=['interval', 'unitCount', 'orderItemCount', 'orderCount', ['averageUnitPrice', 'currencyCode'], ['totalSales', 'currencyCode']])

# Rename the columns for clarity
df.columns = ['Day', 'unitCount', 'orderItemCount', 'orderCount', 'averageUnitPrice', 'curr', 'total sales', 'currency']
print(df)

# Convert UTC datetime range to just the first date
df['Day'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Day'].str.slice(0,10), format="%Y-%m-%d")
print(df)


# Initialize the app
app = Dash()

# App layout
app.layout = [
    html.Div(children='Amazon sales in the last 7 days'),
    dash_table.DataTable(data=df.to_dict('records'), page_size=10),
    dcc.Graph(figure=px.histogram(df, x='Day', y='total sales'))
]

I think it has something to do with pd.to_datetime() in which I'm taking a range of UTC datetimes and using the first 10 chars to make a single date. I say this because if I don't modify the df['Day'] values at all, the histogram matches the datatable. What's going on?
dataframe before converting to datetime:
                                              Day  unitCount  orderItemCount  orderCount  averageUnitPrice curr  total sales currency
0  2024-08-14T00:00-05:00--2024-08-15T00:00-05:00         28              26          26             29.28  USD       819.72      USD
1  2024-08-15T00:00-05:00--2024-08-16T00:00-05:00         24              19          19             32.49  USD       779.76      USD
2  2024-08-16T00:00-05:00--2024-08-17T00:00-05:00         13              12          12             28.45  USD       369.87      USD
3  2024-08-17T00:00-05:00--2024-08-18T00:00-05:00         18              14          14             25.82  USD       464.82      USD
4  2024-08-18T00:00-05:00--2024-08-19T00:00-05:00          8               8           8             24.99  USD       199.92      USD
5  2024-08-19T00:00-05:00--2024-08-20T00:00-05:00         30              25          25             24.99  USD       749.70      USD
6  2024-08-20T00:00-05:00--2024-08-21T00:00-05:00         40              30          30             28.74  USD      1149.60      USD

dataframe after converting to datetime:
          Day  unitCount  orderItemCount  orderCount  averageUnitPrice curr  total sales currency
0  2024-08-14         28              26          26             29.28  USD       819.72      USD
1  2024-08-15         24              19          19             32.49  USD       779.76      USD
2  2024-08-16         13              12          12             28.45  USD       369.87      USD
3  2024-08-17         18              14          14             25.82  USD       464.82      USD
4  2024-08-18          8               8           8             24.99  USD       199.92      USD
5  2024-08-19         30              25          25             24.99  USD       749.70      USD
6  2024-08-20         40              30          30             28.74  USD      1149.60      USD


It doesn't sound like you want a histogram. A histogram bins continuous data to estimate the underling density function. Sounds like you want a bar chart.

You are right. I ended up changing to a bar chart

I have resolved this issue by adding nbins=10 to the Graph creation.
    dcc.Graph(figure=px.histogram(df, x='Day', y='total sales', nbins=10))

